# What does Monit do when it says 'initializing'?

Tags: monitoring, monit

I'm using Monit for system monitoring. If i enable monitoring on a service it shows 'initializing' in the Status row. This can take a while. I wonder what Monit is doing in that time, since the used start script should return in under 2 secs max.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look in `/etc/monit/monitrc`, you'll see one of the options is "`set daemon`" which controls how often Monit checks services.  Mine is set at 120.  So that is the quickest Monit will update what it reports.  The script might return in 2 seconds, but if yours is set like mine Monit won't check it again for another 118 seconds thereafter.

Comment: This line reads `set daemon 10 with start delay 20` in my monitrc. But sometimes it stucks with 'initializing' for more than a minute.

Comment: Does the service take that long to create a .pid file?  IIRC Monit needs that to verify the service is running.

Comment: Actually your answer pointed me into the right direction: The init script i used started monit with the command line parameter `-d` which overrides directives in the config file.

Answer (score 2):

Solved my monit initialization delay caused by a non-responsive SMTP mail server.

Commenting out these two lines in /etc/monit/monitrc were the isloated config change I applied to make my monit restarts really fast!

```
# set mailserver smtp.sendgrid.com
#  username "apikey" password "SG.."
```

These /var/log/monit.log entries helped:

```
[EDT Jun  9 06:28:32] error    : Cannot create socket
 to [smtp.sendgrid.com]:25 -- Connection timed out
[EDT Jun  9 06:28:32] error    : Cannot open a connection to the mailserver 'smtp.sendgrid.com:25' -- Operation now in progress
[EDT Jun  9 06:28:32] error    : Mail: No mail servers are available
```

monit -V

```
This is Monit version 5.16
Built with ssl, with pam and with large files
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Tildeslash Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
```

lsb_release -a

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

uname -a

```
Linux prime3prod 4.4.0-1084-aws #94-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 17 13:10:20 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```